# What does *say* mean in "Say, could you bring us the knife?"?

Tags: filler-words

What is the meaning of **say** in the following sentence:

> - Say, could you bring us the knife?
>   - Knife?
>   - Yeah. Thank you.
>
> (12 Angry Men, 1957)

I can guess that it is some kind of filler word (I don't think *filler* is the right word). But, I couldn't find anything on the web. Can you give some reference about this kind of usage?

Comment: It is from the redundant phrase "I say ...", but you can parse it as an *interjection*.